# installing and import a 'machine' module at pycharm

Tags: module, pycharm, pycrypto

At pycharm, I was trying to use 'machine' module.
`pip install machine` is not working,
So I tried to use 'python package' at pycharm.
But there was error:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  winrand.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: 구문 오류: 식별자 'intmax_t'  ...abbrevation...

error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Refering to other Q&A in stackoverflow, so I had installed **setuptools, wheel** module for solving problem, but they didn't worked.
How can I solve prob?